# Snap a point to a line and get the line ID

Tags: oracle, geometry, gis, oracle-spatial, oracle18c

I have an Oracle 18c database that has SDO_GEOMETRY tables:

- Sidewalk **polyline** table
- Sidewalk inspection **point** table

---

When sidewalk inspection points are created, I want to automatically snap the points to the closest line --and-- insert the line's ID into a column.

[image]

- I'm not interested in snapping to the line vertices (sidewalk deficiencies/inspections don't necessarily occur at vertices). I need to be able to snap to the closest position along the line (even if it is mid-segment).
- The search tolerance would be 5 metres.

---

Is there a way to do this via an Oracle Spatial/SDO_GEOMETRY insert trigger?

*(I've poked around in the docs, but I haven't seen anything so far that lends itself to snapping.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/352809/21232

In a nutshell, the solution is to use the Linear Referencing features of Oracle Spatial